# NodeJS VM2 proper way to access console when set to 'redirect'

Tags: node.js, node-vm2

I'm using the [VM2](https://gist.github.com/pguillory/729616) package to run user code. I'm trying to intercept console output and have set the NodeVM object's console property to 'redirect':

```
    // Create a new sandbox VM for this request
    const vm = new NodeVM( {
        console: 'redirect',
        timeout: 30000,
        sandbox: { request, state, response },
        require: {
            external: true
        }
    });
```

According to the documentation that redirects console output to 'events'. I'm new to NodeJS, how do I hook into those events to capture the console.log messages executed inside the Sandbox?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging through the source code, I found this file where the event emit is occuring:

[sandbox.js](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2/blob/8a1dcad0b1c1bdee5c6d01fffd5a53c6911ab989/lib/sandbox.js)

```
if (vm.options.console === 'inherit') {
    global.console = Contextify.readonly(host.console);
} else if (vm.options.console === 'redirect') {
    global.console = {
        log(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.log', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        },
        info(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.info', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        },
        warn(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.warn', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        },
        error(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.error', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        },
        dir(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.dir', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        },
        time: () => {},
        timeEnd: () => {},
        trace(...args) {
            vm.emit('console.trace', ...Decontextify.arguments(args));
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

All you need to do to listen to these events is to bind an event listener on the vm you've created:

```
// Create a new sandbox VM for this request
    const vm = new NodeVM( {
        console: 'redirect',
        require: {
            external: ['request']
        }
    });

    vm.on('console.log', (data) => {
        console.log(`VM stdout: ${data}`);
      });
```

Likewise, you can bind to console.log, console.info, console.warn, console.error, console.dir, and console.trace. Hopefully this will save someone else some time.